# Hide Keypad on click of textfield IOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield

I am devolepeing an app where i am entering data to  a textfield from custom view(not input view).Problem is that i don't want the system keypad to popup when i touch the textfield.I have gone through [Apple text programming document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) but was not able to find the solution.How to achieve this.

Comment: Why dont you use UILabel then?

Comment: [self.textfield setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Comment: yea could have used but now i have gone far with textfield….have to modify a lot…i got a solution...

Comment: Can you tell the reason of down voting this question?So that i can improve my standards?I don't think the question is stupid.see the no.of answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code may help you

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

if (textField==/**urs testField on which you want to remove keyboard on click*/ ) {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
   //*its depend your requirement
    [here you can call yours custom view];
}
return YES;
}
```

adjust as per req..

Answer (score 4):

You can also use gestures,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)hideKeyboard {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the userInteractionEnabled property:

```
//UITextField *text;
text.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, what exactly you are expecting. I hope that you need to handle the `UITextField` delegates but without `UIKeyboard` : If so, then implement `delegate` of

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{  
// resign the textfield and do your stuff with the data 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign a IBOutlet property to that particular UITextField
and then in viewDidLoad add the following code `[self.YourUITextField setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

Disable the editing for the particular field

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField isEqual:myTextField]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[self.view endEditing:YES]; // this statement will hide keyboard. Useful when we use many textfields based on tag value. 
return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining what this does? It might solve the immediate issue, but currently isn't very educating. Thanks ;)

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; // this statement will hide keyboard. Useful when we use many textfields based on tag value.